# Checking if Registry Key exists not working

Tags: vb.net

I have this function in my program that deletes the specific reg file if it exists. For some reason when this code runs, it comes up with an error message saying that I can not convert a string into a double

Here is my code:

```
Dim RegistryKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("registry key here", True)

If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("registry key here", "Key to delete", Nothing) Is Nothing Then

Else
    RegistryKey.DeleteValue("Key to delete")
End If
```

Here is the error message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you run it in the debugger and indicate which line throws the error, please?

Comment: @Ryan It throws the error at the RegistryKey.DeleteValue line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete a keys from registry must have path as:

```
Dim RegistryKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

Dim keyName As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, True)
```

If `RegistryKey Is Nothing` then the key is not exist otherwise you can do what you want to it as sample delete a subkey as:

```
If Not (RegistryKey Is Nothing) Then
     RegistryKey.DeleteValue("foo")
Else
     MsgBox("not found")
End If
```

If you want to check the value of `foo` and it that exist delet it use :

```
 If RegistryKey.GetValue("foo") Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox("value does not exist")
 Else
      MsgBox("value exist")
 End If
```

Hint about solve your problem:

If you define a `RegistryKey`, then use that for evaluate a subkey exist or not exist in registry as I use `RegistryKey.GetValue("foo")` BUT you use `My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("registry key here", "Key to delete", Nothing) Is Nothing`

Comment: another question, I'm trying to delete these registry values on FormClosed after I click a button (When I click that button, it does Me.Close() after some stuff) but for some reason, those registry values get recreated again, I'm trying to delete some registry values in: Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store  In CurrentUser

Comment: nevermind, the reigstry values get recreated even if I close the program manually

Comment: if the registrykey recreate then you create that in a section in your program, do you create the key twice?